# Return Values With Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, parameters, return-value

I am quite new to programming and I just need help with what I am doing wrong.

This is the code I have so far. Yes, this is for homework, but I am confused on what I have to do next.

In the CreateRandomlyFilledArray method, I have to create an allocated array. This method will take as it's only parameter an integer, The array is then created inside the method, filled with values that have been randomly created by the method. (values can be from 0 to 100).

The array will then be passed (as a parameter) to the PrintArray method, which will take as it's single parameter an array of integers, and will print out everything in the array.

```
class Returning_An_Array
{
    public void RunExercise()
    {
        ArrayReturnMethods m = new ArrayReturnMethods();
        int[] nums1; 
        nums1 = m.CreateRandomlyFilledArray(10);          

        m.PrintArray(nums1);
    }
}

class ArrayReturnMethods
{

    public int[] CreateRandomlyFilledArray( int size )
    {
        int[] newNums = new int[size];
        for (int value = 0; value < newNums.Length; value++)
        {
            return newNums;

        }
        return newNums;

    }

    public void Printarray( int[] value )
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value is: {0}", value[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: You may wish to look at the System.Random class.  Consider how you might use it in a loop in your CreateRandomlyFilledArray function to set the values in your array.  Also your Printarray function doesn't do what you think, you don't want.  Consider placing the array indexing inside your array as a parameter to your WriteLine (Console.WriteLine("{0}", value[I]);)

Comment: Thank you, I made edits based on what I understood from you! Still get errors with the returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid asking homework question here. Especially when a bit of reading would solve your issue. Good luck with your homework. : )

```
class Program
{
    /*
    I assume you are trying to
    1. Create an array of integers
    2. Store random numbers (between 0 and 100) inside that array
    3. Print the numbers in the array 

    You have alot of reading to do as theres alot of fundemental mistakes in both your approach and code.
     */
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // creating an array with random numbers
    ArrayMethods m = new ArrayMethods();
    int[] nums1; 
    nums1 = m.CreateRandomlyFilledArray(10);          

    m.Printarray(nums1);

    }

    class ArrayMethods
    {
        /*
             - First you have to fill the array with random numbers
        In your solution, you have created "CreateRandomlyFilledArray".
         1. You created the a new array of integers which is good
         2. The way you attempted to fill the new array is incorrect
        */
        public int[] CreateRandomlyFilledArray(int size)
        {
            int[] newNums = new int[size];

            Random numGen = new Random(); //  This will be used to generate random numbers
            for (int elementNum = 0; elementNum < newNums.Length; elementNum++)
            {
                // here we will put a random number in every position of the array using the random number generator
                newNums[elementNum] = numGen.Next(0, 100); // we pass in you minimum and maximum into the next function and it will return a random number between them
            }

            // here we will return the array with the random numbers
            return newNums;
        }

        /*
        - This function prints out each item in an integer array
            1. You do not need to a return value as you will not be returning any thing so, Use "void".
        */
        public void Printarray(int[] value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("value is: {0}", value[i]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take your advice with reading more carefully. I have to work on thinking like a programmer cause I am no good at that.